# Undefined variable

Tags: php, mvc

tengo un problema, estoy siguiendo un curso de programación en php y pongo la información tal cual, el problema esque me tira un error al mandar llamar una variable.

Funcion de usuarios

```
<?php
function Users(){
    $db = new Conexion();
    $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    if($db->rows($sql) > 0){
            while($d = $db->recorrer($sql)){
                $users[$d['id']] == array(
                    'id' => $d['id'],
                    'user' => $d['user'],
                    'pass' => $d['pass'],
                    'email' => $d['email'],
                    'permisos' => $d['permisos']

                );
            }
    }else{
     $users = false;
    }

    $db->liberar($sql);
    $db->close();
        return $users;     
    }
?>
```

Llamo la funcion desde core

```
$users = Users(); //ERROR!
```

Comment: ¿Qué error recibes y en qué línea?

Comment: donde esta comentado con _ERROR_ hasta el final de la pregunta, solo me tira **Notice: Undefined variable: users**

Comment: ¿Dónde defines la variable `$users`?

Comment: bueno a eso es a lo que voy, has visto mi código? puedes decirme si es correcto la forma en que lo estoy realizando

Comment: He visto tu código y tiene fallos, por ejemplo tienes un `==` donde debería haber un `=` lo que hará que se compare en lugar de que se asigne la variable `$users`. Y en ese momento `$users` no estará definida y debería dar fallo (o quizás sea en el return, estoy en un móvil y no puedo probar el código). Por eso te preguntaba por la definición de la variable.

Comment: Estas utilizando algún framework? De no ser así incluiste el archivo que contiene la función Users en el archivo donde la llamas? Sería bueno que colooques el archivo donde haces referencia a la Users(), para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no definiste la variable $users y el == en vez de = en la asignación dentro del while. Sin ver la clase Conexion no sabría decirte si lo demás esta correcto.

```
<?php
function Users(){
    $db = new Conexion();
    $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    $users = array();
    if($db->rows($sql) > 0){
        while($d = $db->recorrer($sql)){
            $users[$d['id']] = array(
                'id' => $d['id'],
                'user' => $d['user'],
                'pass' => $d['pass'],
                'email' => $d['email'],
                'permisos' => $d['permisos']

            );
        }
    } else {
      $users = false;
    }
    $db->liberar($sql);
    $db->close();
    return $users;     
}
?>
```